# In Robinson Crusoe, what happens when you lose an item that acts as an invention prerequisite?

Tags: robinson-crusoe

During the game Robinson Crusoe, you can "invent" items around camp, and some items act as prerequisites for others.  E.g. You cannot build a furnace without brick, and you cannot build a fireplace without fire.

Various events can destroy those items.  On page 16, of the Portal Edition rulebook it states that when flipping a item card over, that "If the Item had an additional effect, you should cancel it if possible.

Assuming that a player has already built the "furnace" invention, after building the necessary invention "brick", and that an event forces the player to destroy the invented brick invention (as a choice among those available), then does that mean the invented furnace is destroyed as well?  Or does the furnace remain available, even after the brick is removed, because it was already invented?

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a direct answer for this in the [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Robinson.pdf), but there are a couple of very closely-related cases:

On page 16, under *Unexplored terrain type*, the rules note that when you lose access to the last tile of a particular terrain type, you lose access to that terrain type and cannot *build* items that still require it, but you also *do not lose* any Items that you have already built.

A little further down, under *Turning Items to Invention side*, the only changes noted are that

> If that item was required for building another Item or taking a specific Threat Action, you cannot do it now.

Combining those two sections, I reason that if you lose a prerequisite Item, **you do not lose any Item you have already completed construction on as a result of that prerequisite Item.** The main idea is that those prerequisite Items *allow you to construct* other Items; once you have constructed those other items, the prerequisite Item has no further function.

Think of it this way: the Brick invention means you have a *source of Bricks;* losing the Brick invention does not mean that any existing items suddenly cease to exist. (Also consider another case: the Shovel allows you to build a Cellar. Does losing your Shovel mean that your Cellar disappears in a puff of logic? It certainly isn't made of shovels.)

Comment: '_it certainly isn't made of shovels_' damn I have been building them wrong all this time.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a direct rule for this (on page 18) in the edition of the rules that I have, and the answer is:

> **Built Items that had the flipped Item as a requirement are not affected.**
>
> [...]
>
> Example:
>
> If you lose the *Map*, you can no longer
>   build the *Shortcut*. If you had already built the *Shortcut*, you
>   keep it.